# Update widget when preferences changed using custom broadcast

Tags: android, widget, android-broadcast

I need to update my app's widget every time the settings are changed by the user.

I have a settings activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

public static final String customIntent = "CUSTOM_SETTINGS_CHANGED";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new MainActivity.SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                                      String key) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(customIntent);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

I've added that custom intent to the manifest:

```
<action android:name="CUSTOM_SETTINGS_CHANGED" />
```

But the widget is not updated immediately after the settings are changed. So my custom broadcast either is not sent or not received. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: @ci it's not this, all the other intents for the same receiver work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a different approach.

In my **main activity** I've added this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    <...>
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(customIntent);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    };
    <...>
}
```

It seems that `onSharedPreferenceChanged` was never called for some reason. I don't know why but at least I've found a way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
// this part important in manifest declaration
package com.xmpls.onetwothree.abc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SettingsActivity {


    public class SettingsActivity extends Activity implements 
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
        // Change like this
        public static final String CUSTOM_SETTINGS_CHANGED = "com.xmpls.onetwothree.abc.custompls";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Display the fragment as the main content.
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            /* More code here. . .*/
        }
        /* And some here. . .*/
    }
================================================================================
and in manifest U must registred ACTION like this:
<action android:name="com.xmpls.onetwothree.abc.CUSTOM_SETTINGS_CHANGED" />
```